# ember simple auth invalidate other user

Tags: postgresql, ember.js, sails.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I'm new to ember-simple-auth and I need some help.
Say, there are 3 users, User A is Admin, User B and C are User. User C somehow able to hack User B's account and currently is logged in as User B. User B asked User A to reset his password.

I want to invalidate User C's session (who is currently logged in as User B) after User A reset User B's password.

I'm thinking of saving each user's session in a database and every time the user logs out, the session in database is also removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete or reset the user's token on the server side. The next time they make a request with the old token they'd receive a 401 and will be logged out.